# How to align buttons in a card using html boostrap

Tags: html, button, bootstrap-4, alignment, card

I'm looking for a solution to get all my buttons in one horizontal line.[image]

There a two different problems with this alignment:

1. The "Find out more" buttons in every card are immediately after the last text row and therefore not in a horizontal line.
2. The "Factsheet"-Button is in the order of the "Find out more" buttons a `<button>` element and therefore by default not in an horizontal line with the other elemts.

How can I solve my problem(s)? I tried some changes within the CSS file (like `margin-top: auto;`), but that didn't work.

Here a snippet of my actual html code:

```
<div class="card-body" style="padding: 0">
      <p class="card-text">        
        <ul>
            <li>text</li>                
            <li>text</li>
        </ul>
        <span style="padding: 1.25em;"><a href="text.html" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary stretched-link">Find out more</a> </span>
    <button>
            <span style="padding: 1.25em;"><a href="text.pdf" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary stretched-link" target="_blank">Factsheet</a> </span>
    </button>
      </p>
    </div>
```

and the according CSS:

```
.project_card_body {
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 1.25rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `.card-deck` or `.card-group`, you can use a `div.card-footer` in each card to hold the buttons and just use `a.btn` for the buttons.

```
<div class="card-deck">
  ...
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <a href="text.html" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" style="padding: 1.25em;">Find out more</a>
      <a href="text.pdf" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" style="padding: 1.25em;" target="_blank">Factsheet</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4p0y6qcg/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution works in content of alignment, but not in it's functionality. Because with your solution both buttons are doing the same if I click on them. :-(

Comment: Do you have an event listener? They are two different links with different href values, if that is happening it is due to something you have not shared. Your question just asks about alignment.

Comment: Hi, there is no event listener. I fixed the problem by using <button><a href... instead of just <a href... Do you know how I can change the layout of the footer? It is a very large fold with a gray border. I want a smaller box, bigger buttons and a white border. The box itself was grey too. I changed it to white by using <div class="card-footer bg-white" instead of <div class="card-footer"